# Azcopy linux include option for download

Tags: linux, azure, azcopy

I have a blob where I was downloading everything on it like this:

```
azcopy --source https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer --destination ./ --dest-key <key> --recursive
```

Now I only want to download specific files from this container. From the documentation [`--include "a*"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux) will *upload* only files with prefix `a`.

How can I use wildcards or pattern to *download* `.txt` files?

I tried:

```
azcopy --source https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer --destination ./ --dest-key <key> --recursive -include "*.txt"
```

or

```
--include '*.txt'
--include *.txt
```

Seems it works only for uploading files.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Yes, how to run the `rm` command is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Most command questions are better asked at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Let's us move all post with Linux and AzCopy to somewhere else! yay!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, AzCopy doesn't support wildcards when source location is blob, since Azure Storage Blob service doesn't have such API to list blobs with a wildcard.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your precise answer. I'll use `find` to remove all unwanted files.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to do it locally. :)

Answer (score 0):

The option to match the blob names is achieved using the Pattern attribute.

```
AzCopy /Source:https://<your_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your_container_name>/<your_sub_directory_at_blob>  /Dest:<your_local_directory> /SourceKey:<your_account_key> /Pattern:<file_pattern> /S
```

For example you use *.txt to download all the text files

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount1-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/mynewcontainer1 /Dest:https://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/mynewcontainer2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:*.txt
```

Comment: I didn't saw this attribute on the linux `Azcopy`. Are you sure this attribute exist for Linux?

Comment: my bad. I did not realize if the linux version is different. Am not sure.